# Delphi - Re-split an array of string?

Tags: arrays, sqlite, delphi, split

Let's say I have a string like this :

```
string1 := 'me,email1,you,email2,him,email3,them,email4';
```

To turn this into an array of string I simply do :

```
array1 := SplitString(string1,',');
```

This works fine.

But then, I get an array like :

```
array1[0] -> me
array1[1] -> email1
array1[2] -> you
array1[3] -> email2
array1[4] -> him
array1[5] -> email3
array1[6] -> them
array1[7] -> email4
```

I've searched a long time how to insert into SQLIte with this but there is no using

```
for i:= 0 to length(array1) -1
SQLExecute('INSERT INTO table(name,email) VALUES("'+array1[i]+'","'+array1[i+1]+'"');
```

because index 0 will be inserted as name with index 1 as email, but on the next turn, index 1 will be inserted as name with index 2 as email, when index 1 is en email, and index 2 a name... do you see the problem ?

I thought about re-spliting the first array into a second one by changing the initial string format into :

```
string1 := 'me-email1,you-email2,him-email3,them-email4';
```

to split a first time on the ' and a second time on the -, to get a 2 dimensional array, but seems this concept is over my knowledge at the moment :)

Just for the record, the Delphi RAD I'm using is quite recent, and only a few functions / tools are available at the moment.

How would you insert into sql ? Would you keep the original String format, or change it to get a 2 dimensional array ?

Comment: What you really want to do is parse into an array of records, with each record having a field for name and one for e-mail.

Comment: a really Terrible idea for any language. Delphi PHP, Python - whatever!!! Please use reliable methods!  http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate in pairs:

```
for i := 0 to length(array1) div 2 - 1 do
  SQLExecute('INSERT INTO table(name,email) VALUES("'+array1[i*2]+'","'+array1[i*2+1]+'"');
```

Answer (score 0):

You just should not use per-INSERT FOR-loop here.
It is not suited for it and it is dangerous if your string would have 3 or 7 or any other odd number of elements.

Also splicing random data right into the SQL command is extremely unreliable and fragile. http://bobby-tables.com/

You should either use a WHILE-loop with a sliding fetcher or tick-tock (finite state machine) swinging in one-per-string FOR-loop.

```
var q: TQuery; 
// some Query-component of any library, 
//   including DBX, AnyDAC/ FireDAC  mORMot or any other library you would use

var sa_OK, sa_err1, sa_err2: TArray<string>;

// common preparations for both methods
q.ParamCheck := True;
q.SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO table(name,email) VALUES( :PName, :PMail )';
q.Prepared := True;

sa_OK := TArray<string>.Create( 'me','email1','you','email2','him','email3','them','email4');
// eeeaaasy example

sa_err1 := TArray<string>.Create( 'me','email1','you','email2','him'); 
// check this out-of-sync error too - it can happen! you should be pre-aware!

sa_err2 := TArray<string>.Create( 'Sarah O''Connor','email1','"Bobby F. Kennedy"','email2','him'#0'again','email3');
// not the letters you expected - but they can come too

Procedure Method1_Fetcher( const sa: array of string );
var i: integer;
    s: string;
  function Fetched: Boolean;
  begin
    Result := i <= High(sa);
    if Result then begin
       s := sa[i];
       Inc(i);
    end;
  end;
Begin
  i := Low(sa);
  while true do begin
    if not Fetched then break;
    q.Params[1].AsWideString := s;

    if not Fetched then break;
    q.Params[2].AsWideString := s;

   //  ...you can easily add more parameters for more columns
   //  if not Fetched then break;
   //  q.Params[3].Value := s;
   //  ... or you can make a loop 
   //  FOR j := 0 to q.Params.Count - 1 DO ... q.Params[j] :=...

   // only executing insert if ALL the columns were filled
    q.ExecSQL;  
  end;

  q.Transaction.CommitWork;
End;

Procedure Method2_TickTock( const sa: array of string );
var i, FSM: integer;
Begin

  FSM := 0;
  for i := Low(sa) to High(sa) do begin

    if FSM = 0 then begin
       q.ParamByName('PName').AsWideString := sa[i];

       FSM := 1; // next mode of tick-tock
       Continue;
    end; 
    if FSM = 1 then begin
       q.ParamByName('PMail').AsWideString := sa[i];
       q.ExecSQL;
    // only executing insert after the last column was filled

       FSM := 0; // next mode of tick-tock
       Continue;
    end;

    /// would only come here if we made some mistake above 
    /// and FSM got impossible value - so no "Continue" was executed   
    ///  show error and exit

    raise EInvalidOperation.CreateFmt('FSM = %d', [FSM]);
  end;

  q.Transaction.CommitWork;
End;

Procedure Method3_SimplifiedFSM( const sa: array of string ); 
// this method is actually are streamlined method #2
// it can be made because all our steps are TOTALLY identical
//   ( sans optional insert execution )
var i, FSM: integer;
Begin

  FSM := 0;
  for i := Low(sa) to High(sa) do begin

    q.Params[ FSM ].AsWideString := sa[i];
    Inc( FSM );
    if FSM >= q.Params.Count then begin
      q.ExecSQL; // only after (if ) last of all columns filled!
      FSM := 0; 
    end; 

  end;
  q.Transaction.CommitWork;
End;
```

Now you can debug calls like `Method1(sa_OK)` or `Method2(sa_err1)` and see how it is working and how it deals with errors

Comment: I love that solution, but it's too complex at the time for me.
Thank you for taking the time to answer me, and sorry it took me so long to answer.

Comment: the efforts to recover after unexpected and maybe malicious input would be far worse...